# Phone Number Formatting while you type for 7 / 10 /11 digits

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a script here that will format a 10-digit number string to (555)-555-5555 and a 11-digit number string (if leading number is (1)) to 1(555)-555-5555. I am trying to have this script also format a 7-digit number to 555-5555, but I have been unsuccessful in my many attempts. Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/9cv2r/ Anyone have any insight? Here is what I have so far:

```
/* FORMAT PHONE BEHAVIOR MASK */ 
function FormatPhone (e,input) { 
    /* to prevent backspace, enter and other keys from  
     interfering w mask code apply by attribute  
     onkeydown=FormatPhone(control) 
    */ 
    evt = e || window.event; /* firefox uses reserved object e for event */ 
    var pressedkey = evt.which || evt.keyCode; 
    var BlockedKeyCodes = new Array(8,27,13,9); //8 is backspace key 
    var len = BlockedKeyCodes.length; 
    var block = false; 
    var str = ''; 
    for (i=0; i<len; i++){ 
       str=BlockedKeyCodes[i].toString(); 
       if (str.indexOf(pressedkey) >=0 ) block=true;  
    } 
    if (block) return true; 
 
   s = input.value; 
   if (s.charAt(0) =='+') return false; 
   filteredValues = '"`!@#$%^&*()_+|~-=\QWERT YUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:ZXCVBNM<>?qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;zxcvbnm,./\\\'';  
   var i; 
   var returnString = ''; 
   
   /* Search through string and append to unfiltered values  
      to returnString. */ 

   for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {  
         var c = s.charAt(i); 

         //11-Digit number format if leading number is 1

         if (s.charAt(0) == 1){
            if ((filteredValues.indexOf(c) == -1) & (returnString.length <  14 )) { 
                if (returnString.length==1) returnString +='('; 
                if (returnString.length==5) returnString +=')'; 
                if (returnString.length==6) returnString +='-'; 
                if (returnString.length==10) returnString +='-'; 
                returnString += c; 
            } 
         }

        //10-digit number format 
         else{
             if ((filteredValues.indexOf(c) == -1) & (returnString.length <  13 )) { 
                    if (returnString.length==0) returnString +='('; 
                    if (returnString.length==4) returnString +=')'; 
                    if (returnString.length==5) returnString +='-'; 
                    if (returnString.length==9) returnString +='-'; 
                    returnString += c; 
                }
         } 
             
    } 
   input.value = returnString; 
    
   return false}
```

Comment: Until your server reboots, here's your code in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9cv2r/